# simplexml update xml file permission issue on ubuntu server

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a permission issue when I try to update an xml file with simplexml `$xml->asXML('my.xml')`; and I have been trying to change the permissions on file `chmod 777 my.xml` but doesn't seems to work.

What other alternatives I have ?

Comment: have you set the permission of the folder containing it to 777 too?

Comment: but is a production server

Comment: you can set it via chmod, and after update you can set it back to 666 or whatever you want

Comment: There is rarely a case when it makes sense to use file permission `777`. Decide which accounts require rights to do what and chose a permission mode, a user and a group that actually makes sense. Do not try around, think instead.

Comment: @arkascha yes I agree with you, but this just in case of trying, about the problem he facing right now, usually I set the umask to 0777 before editing and set it again to 0666 after editing

Comment: @nayoso Why should one want to try around? I do not see any reason for this. Apart from that: why on earth execution right on a xml file? This does _not_ make sense, sorry. I suspect some people do this 'trying around' business when they do not know what they actually want. That is not good.

Comment: okay let me tell a bit more about a php file gets a request, let's call itt reciver.php which is validating a token. If token is valid I want to update a node value in my.xml and save it back. On windows development I do not have this problem.

Comment: Neither the question nor the above discussion actually explain the problem you are having. What "doesn't seem to work" - changing the permissions (in which case *why* you are changing the permissions is irrelevant) or writing to the file afterwards (in which case we need to know exactly what errors you are seeing, etc).